# lua change colors rgb watermark drewtext

Tags: lua

how can I do something like that but that it will change colors?
i have that for a specific color

```
render.draw_text(font, 15, 10, "tired-dev.xyz", 5, 5, 5, 255, true, false, false)
```

like a watermark that changes colors randomly with a list of colors or something like  that
like in css or c that you can do

Answer (score -1):

Guessing 5 5 5 is your color and 255 is the alpha value, so it's using 8-bit values instead of floats.  Who knows what true / false is here, fill..?

```
local r = math.random( 0, 255 )
local g = math.random( 0, 255 )
local b = math.random( 0, 255 )
local a = 255

render.draw_text(font, 15, 10, "tired-dev.xyz", r, g, b, a, true, false, false)
```

Comment: yo that helps but that kinda give epilepsy if u could help slow it down that will be lit

Comment: Don't know what app you're using.  Looks similar to Love2D, but not exatly.  Just put those `math.random()` calls before your draw loop, maybe in a function every time you need them to change.  I'd have to see more to tell ya where.